# Switching comma to a dot during calculation and making it able to calculate

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, calculator

I am currently playing around with jQuery and I am trying to make a calculator. I realised that you cannot use commas during a calculation. Instead of using a comma you need to use a dot.

Is there maybe a way to switch that? Till now I've build this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#price,#supply").keyup(function(){
      var price = $('#price').val();
      var supply = $('#supply').val();
      var total = price * supply;
      
      $('#total').val(total);
      
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="price" id="price">
<input type="text" name="supply" id="supply">
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="0">
```

My goal is to enter a comma instead of a dot during inserting values in the inputs. I want to make the comma calculateable.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup Javascript documentation for `Number` - There, I read this:

> The new locales and options arguments let applications specify the language whose formatting conventions should be used and customize the behavior of the function. In older implementations, which ignore the locales and options arguments, the locale used and the form of the string returned are entirely implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .replace to convert the commas into nothing before they're calculated, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#price,#supply").keyup(function(){
      var price = $('#price').val().replace(/,/g,'');
      var supply = $('#supply').val().replace(/,/g,'');

      var total = price * supply;

      $('#total').val(total);

  });
});
```